# PHP & SQL check email exist and read password_hash befor change email

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to check email and get password_hash with single SQL-query?
I need it to check, if email already exist in database please choose an other email.

I ask for a password befor email will changed.

Example-Query:

```
$getData = "SELECT email,password_hash FROM memberData WHERE email = 'example@example.com' OR user_id != 10";
```

Or i need two different querys

```
$searchEmail = "SELECT email FROM memberData LIMIT 1";

$seachPassword = "SELECT password_hash FROM memberData WHERE user_id = 10 LIMIT 1";
```

For password i using password_hash(); function.

Comment: Select the user with the email, verify the password hash with PHP and update the email if it works. There's no way to validate the hash inside a query since it's a PHP function that validates it

Comment: Your first query would always return a list of users, even if the email isn't found. Is that the expected result?

Comment: ^ You need to verify your hash with [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) and not through raw text. Every time you call `password_hash` it generates a _new_ value because the first part includes a salt - you can't guess this salt and therefore you can't look it up directly in the DB.